# Macbook 13 inch - Screen Noise on attached display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I have a 13 Inch Macbook (2014) running Yosemite -  the computer has been attached to an external dell monitor via the HDMI port. The screen works fine but on waking the computer from sleep, I see noise (see image below) on the external monitor. I have to plug out the monitor and plug it in again to make it work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like timing issue between monitor and your Macbook.

You might try different cable or just turning monitor off and on with a button (much better than wearing off HDMI socket btw)